# Getting Content type 'application/json' not supported

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I am getting below exception when i am using `@RequestBody` in my controller class.

But I need to use `@RequestBody` only for post method.

> Caused by: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException:
>   Content type 'application/json' not supported

Anyone can help how to solve this issue..

Comment: are you using lombok?

Answer (score 3):

you can add this annotation

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

or put this dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
<version>2.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this in my unit tests, even though I had all the correct annotations on the Controller methods, and I was correctly setting the Content-Type in my request.

Error - 
`Caused by: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json' not supported`

After debugging `AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters` , I realized there were no registered message converters that supported `application/json` .

`@AutoConfigureMockMvc` doesn't register all the converters, but `@WebMvcTest` does.
I changed the test annotation, and the problem was solved.

Previously I was using -

```
@SpringJUnitWebConfig
@ContextConfiguration
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ReportControllerTests {
```

Now using the `@WebMvcTest` which registers the additional message converters.

```
@SpringJUnitWebConfig
@ContextConfiguration
@WebMvcTest(controllers = ReportController.class)
public class ReportControllerTests {
```

Comment: Any tips on debugging this? How were you able to see that there were no message converters configured?

Comment: I put a breakpoint in this method, from my IDE, then inspected the local variable that contained a list of message converters. I don't remember any more than that =\. `AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters`

Comment: I figured a breakpoint, just wasn't sure where to set the breakpoint. So I'm assuming you mean that class/method you mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: You saved my day, dude. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Make sure that you have a correctly jackson version using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
     <version>2.8.0</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
     <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
     <version>2.8.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

As for me, when I use the version of v2.7.6 or v2.8.7. This error came to me! And I change to v2.8.0, It work well!

Secondly, Make sure your controller code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON}, consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public class UserController extends GenericController<User, String> {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public ResponseMessage add(@RequestBody User user) {
       String id = getService().insert(user);
       return ResponseMessage.created(id );
    }
}
```

RequestBody:

```
{
    "username":"123",
    "password":"123",
    "name":"123",
    "phone":"123",
    "email":"123@qq.com",
    "status":1
}
```

Postman :

[Postman Post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TV1V9.png)

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `consumes="application/json"` attribute in the `@RequestMapping`. If not please put that in the annotation and then try. Also if that doesn't work, try using `contentNegotiator`, you can google it for `contentNegotiation` for spring.

Answer (score 0):

Try it without consumer and producer options in @PutMapping.

```
@PutMapping(value = "/lists/{ListName}/item")
```

Answer (score 0):

add jackson-databind in pom.xml solved my problem:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

there is **NO** need to add consumes:
`consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE`

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue. Now i fixed it by the following steps

In Controller

```
@RequestMapping(consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

In pom.xml include the below dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
<version>2.9.4</version>
</dependency>
```